# Пишу программу на Python 3, которая должна выводить все четные элементы списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ошибка:  File "main.py", line 2

```
for i in range(len(a)+1):

                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Код:

```
a = list(map(int,input().split())
for i in range(len(a)+1):
    if i%2==0 :
        print(i)
```

Вообще ноль идей, что ему не нравится.. Двоеточия вроде все на местах

Comment: посчитайте количество скобок в первой строке

Comment: В заголовке нужно указывать, какая проблема или ошибка, а не какую программу ты пишешь (это мало кого интересует).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первой строке не хватает в конце скобки:

```
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in range(len(a)+1):
    if i%2==0 :
        print(i)
```

И так вы будете выводить чётные индексы. Если вы хотите выводить чётные элементы массива, то можно сделать так:

```
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in a:
    if i%2==0 :
        print(i)
```